# MS Access Command Line Args Not Working In Virtual PC

Tags: ms-access, virtual-pc, command-line-arguments

My associate is using Win 7 Pro 64bit, and running an MS Access 2003 application in a Virtual PC (setup as Win XP).

It appears that the Access command line arguments are being ignored: both **/cmd [myString]**, and **/decompile**.

Although not a crucial problem, has anyone else come across this - or other MS Access probs whilst running in VPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your shortcut target include the path and file name of the msaccess.exe?  For example:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 2003\OFFICE11\MSACCESS.EXE" 
"Q:\1 access\NewsgroupAnswers.mdb" /cmd "XXX"

That said my Auto FE Updater, which uses the above syntax, does work just fine on 64 bit OSs so I'm not sure what else the problem might be.

Comment: Hi Tony - as usual, you've nailed it! Lynn added the msaccess.exe path, and the args work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, the fact that Access (or any other program) is running inside a VPC should not make a difference to said program.  Does it ignore any command line arguments?  Perhaps it's worth trying to /repair the database inside the VPC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running MS Access 2007 inside Virtual PC 2005 which in turn is running on Windows 2003 64 bit.  The command passing works exactly as in a non-virtual machine.  Here's the command I use:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSAccess.EXE" "\\Files\Data\NERM\NermMaster.mdb" /x "macDoNerm" /CMD RollRate
```